# How to display custom post in archive section of the wordpress page?

Tags: custom-post-types, archives, custom-post-type-archives

I am using Wordpress Version 4.6.1. I created a Custom Post Type **(CPT)** named **Portfolio**. It works fine. But the problem is I want the custom posts to display in the archive(**'Archives'**) section of my web page in sidebar as other normal posts do.

My CPT now, is getting displayed in the categories section due to this code below :

```
 function namespace_add_custom_types( $query ) 
 {
   if( is_category() || is_tag() && empty( $query->query_vars['suppress_filters'] ) ) 
  {
      $query->set( 'post_type', array('post', 'nav_menu_item', 'portfolio'));
      return $query;
  }
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'namespace_add_custom_types' );
```

I have checked all the questions posted here. Didnt get any help from it.

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear. It looks like you want a widget to display custom posts. Right?

Comment: @cjbj  I already mentioned in my question that I created a custom post but I just want those posts  which are created under **Portfolio(my CPT)** to be listed in the archives automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this shortcode in your archives page:

[catlist id=7]

You can find "id" on the url of category